# JAVA - How to replace string in a binary file (.exe) using regex pattern

Tags: java, python, io, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I need to read a file named "chromedriver.exe" and replace all the occurrences of a string that starts with "cdc_" and is 26 characters long. So, my regex is "cdc_.{22}". That matches a string that starts with "cdc_" and after that has 22 characters.  (example of the string -> cdc_kwjeorialeksjeiwRTkwjr)

My replacement will be this string of 26 characters "plp_roepstdlwoeproslPOweos".

I have this code in python (not mine) that does what I described above, but I need to convert it in Java.
**So the question is: how do I do this in Java?** Please help.

```
import io
import re
import string

replacement = "plp_roepstdlwoeproslPOweos".encode()

with io.open("chromedriver.exe", "r+b") as fh:
    for line in iter(lambda: fh.readline(), b""):
        if b"cdc_" in line:
            fh.seek(-len(line), 1)
            newline = re.sub(b"cdc_.{22}", replacement, line)
            fh.write(newline)
```

Comment: Please show the Java code and explain in detail the error. "tried some solutions but they didn't work" is not enough information. How should we find the bug without any information? Since you have a working solution in Python you can easily compare the resulting file with the expected file (as output of your Python script).

Comment: First, you should post your Java code so we can help you improve it. But generally you don't read a binary file as text and do String replacements in Java. Because Java converts these `byte`s to `char`s and on writing in reverse. That is deadly for a binary. Read the file into a `byte[]`, then do a seek and replacement there, afterwards write the byte array back to the file.

Comment: @vanje there is no error. I'm actually asking how to do it in Java.

Comment: @Sascha i won't post my Java code because the approach is totally wrong and I opened the binary as a text file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a quick and dirty approach. Read the file into a byte array, search for the text, replace if found, then write back to the file.

```
private void replace(String filename) throws Exception
{
    File file=new File(filename);
    int length=(int)file.length();
    byte[] data;
    try(FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(file); 
        ByteArrayOutputStream bs=new ByteArrayOutputStream(length))
    {
        byte[] buffer=new byte[128_000];
        int len=0;
        while((len=in.read(buffer))>0)
            bs.write(buffer,0,len);
        in.close();
        bs.close();
        data=bs.toByteArray();
    }
    searchAndReplace(data);
    
    try(FileOutputStream out=new FileOutputStream(file);
        ByteArrayInputStream bs=new ByteArrayInputStream(data))
    {
        byte[] buffer=new byte[128_000];
        int len=0;
        while((len=bs.read(buffer))>0)
            out.write(buffer,0,len);
        bs.close();
        out.flush();
        out.close();
    }
}

private void searchAndReplace(byte[] data)
{
    byte[] replacements="plp_roepstdlwoeproslPOweos".getBytes(StandardCharsets.US_ASCII);
    byte[] first="cdc_".getBytes(StandardCharsets.US_ASCII);
    Pattern test=Pattern.compile("cdc_.{22}");
    
    for(int i=0;i<data.length-replacements.length;i++)
    {
        if(data[i]==first[0] && data[i+1]==first[1] && data[i+2]==first[2] && data[i+3]==first[3]) // check for consecutive bytes 
        {
            String text=new String(data, i, replacements.length, StandardCharsets.US_ASCII);
            if(test.matcher(text).matches()) // found it
            {
                System.arraycopy(replacements, 0, data, i, replacements.length);
                i+=replacements.length;
            }
        }
    }
}
```